# How to store mongodb aggregate query result in spring mongotemplate?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I am using an aggregate query in mongodb to find the sum of an attribute in all the documents present in a collection.

**Query**:

```
db.conversation.aggregate(   [
{
    $match:{
        $and:[{"mailBoxId":"1","isHidden":false}]
        }
},
 {
   $group:
     {
       _id: {"mailBoxId":"$mailBoxId","isHidden":"$isHidden"} ,
       messageCount: { $sum:"$messageCount" }
     }
 }
]);
```

The **result** returned by Mongodb is fine and is in this format.

```
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : {
            "mailBoxId" : "2",
            "isHidden" : false
        },
        "messageCount" : 2
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

I just want the messageCount field. I am using MongoTemplate(Spring) class to query the database.

```
Query retrievalQuery = new Query();
    retrievalQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("mailBoxId").is(userId).and("isHidden").is(false));
    return mongoTemplate.find(retrievalQuery, );
```

I am confused how to store the resultant object returned by Mongodb and extract a specific field from it.

Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to use aggregate in mongoTemplate is wrong . Try this i am sure it will help.

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        Aggregation.match(
                Criteria.where("mailBoxId").is("1").and("isHidden").is(false)),
        Aggregation.group("$mailBoxId").sum("$unReadMessagesCount").as("unReadMessagesCount")
    );


System.out.println("Query  ==>>["+agg.toString()+"]");
AggregationResults<AggResultObj> data = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "collectionName", AggResultObj.class);

System.out.println("UnReadMesasgeCode :"+data.getUniqueMappedResult().getUnReadMessagesCount());
```

**The AggResultObj will be looks like**

```
public class AggResultObj{
    String _id;
    int unReadMessagesCount;

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }
    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }
    public int getUnReadMessagesCount() {
        return unReadMessagesCount;
    }
    public void setUnReadMessagesCount(int unReadMessagesCount) {
        this.unReadMessagesCount = unReadMessagesCount;
    }
}
```

For more information you can see my blog where i have created a example for the same for your scenario. please click https://satishkumardangi.blogspot.in/2016/09/using-mongo-db-aggregation-with-spring.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Query retrievalQuery = new Query();
    retrievalQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("mailBoxId").is(userId).and("isHidden").is(false));
var result = mongoTemplate.find(retrievalQuery);
var final = result[1].messageCount;
    return final;
```

Comment: Thanks Wasiq. Can you please tell the result data type. I know final would be int.

Comment: This did not solve the problem. I am still wondering what object does mongo db return and how to save it in java.

Comment: result by mongo is a `document` object you can save it as normal objects